# prevent looping in kineticjs sprite animation

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm developing a board game with kineticjs, where a pice is animated simultaneously in 2 ways:

1 - animate with a tween the x and y coordinates, from place a to b. i do this without a problem, getting input from user.

2 - in a sprite, we should see the piece being lift up (frames 0 > 4), and staying up during the previous animation, and in the end of it, it animates from 4 to 8, and goes back goes to the initial idle state

[image]

So far I have this:

```
var animations = {
   idle: [{x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100}],
   up: [{x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
    {x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
    {x: 200, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
    {x: 300, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100}],
   down: [{x: 400, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
    {x: 500, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
    {x: 600, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
    {x: 700, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100}]
};

/* coordinates_js is an array of the possible x and y coordinates for the player. like this, the player is created in the first coordinate, the starting point
        */
        var player = new Kinetic.Sprite({
               x: coordinates_js[0].x,
               y: coordinates_js[0].y,
               image: imageObj,
               animation: 'idle',
               animations: animations,
               frameRate: 7,
               index: 0,
               scale: 0.4,
               id: "player"
            });
    imageObj.onload = function() {

       var targetx = null;
       var targety = null;
       var targetIndex = null;
       var playerIndex = 0;


       document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', function() {
        targetIndex = document.getElementById("targetIndex").value;

        var destino = coordinates_js[targetIndex];

        var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
           node: player,
           x: destino.x,
           y: destino.y,
           rotation: 0,
           duration: 5
        }).play();

        console.log("x: " + destino.x + "y: " + destino.y)

        playerIndex = targetIndex;

        tween.play();


        player.setAnimation("up");
        player.afterFrame(3, function(){
           console.log("idle")
           player.setAnimation("idle");
        })
       }, false);

       playLayer.add(player);
       stage.add(playLayer);

       player.start();
    }
```

the proble here is that the sprite animation plays from 1 to 4 and goes to idle; i neet it to stay up until the end of the tween. i could have:

```
player.setAnimation("up");
player.afterFrame(3, function(){
  console.log("idle")
  player.setAnimation("idle");
})
```

this lifts up the piece, but wont let it drop. So, how can i do like in flash gotoAndPlay("up") to start, and in the end of the tween gotoAndStop("idle").

many thanks to you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the `onFinish` event for tweens?

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-transition-callback-with-kineticjs/

You could do something like this:

```
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: player,
  x: destino.x,
  y: destino.y,
  rotation: 0,
  duration: 5,
  onFinish: function() {
    player.setAnimation("idle"); //When tween finishes, go back to "idle" animation
  }
}).play(); //Play the Tween

player.setAnimation("up"); //Start the "up" animation for the sprite
```